# Is it OK to use this in a contract? Resetting the admin of a contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I'm developing a contract that has an admin.
That admin has some functions only he can call and I'm calling them from a server. Now my biggest fear is that the server is compromised and someone gets the private-key for said admin.

That's why I thought about putting a function that I can use to reset the admin.

The function looks like so:

```
    address private constant emergency_admin = 0x...;
    address private admin = 0x...;
      function emergency(address newa, bytes32 h, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s,bytes32 h2, uint8 v2, bytes32 r2, bytes32 s2)
          public
        {
          //check if the signed messages match the new addres
          require(h==prefixedHash2(newa));
          require(h2==prefixedHash2(newa));
          //check if admin and emergency_admin signed the messages
          require(ecrecover(h, v, r, s)==admin);
          require(ecrecover(h2, v2, r2, s2)==emergency_admin);
          //set new admin
          admin = newa;
        }
        function prefixedHash2(address message)
          private
          pure
          returns (bytes32)
        {
            bytes32 h = keccak256(message);
            bytes memory prefix = "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32";
            bytes32 prefixedHashe = keccak256(prefix, h);
            return prefixedHashe;
        }
```

The `emergency_admin` private-key would obviously not be saved on the server. More like on a piece of paper in a safe.

I'm wondering if this is acceptable or even makes any sense, or if there are way better solutions to this I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a reasonable approach, but there's no need for the parameters `h` and `h2`. I would also consider whether you want the ability to change `emergency_admin` in case *that* gets compromised.

Here's a minor rewrite of your code that drops `h` and `h2` and allows changing both admin accounts:

```
address private admin = 0x...;
address private emergencyAdmin = 0x...;

function emergency(
    address newAdmin,
    address newEmergencyAdmin,
    uint8 v,
    bytes32 r,
    bytes32 s,
    uint8 v2,
    bytes32 r2,
    bytes32 s2
)
    public
{
    bytes32 h = prefixedHash(abi.encodePacked(newAdmin, newEmergencyAdmin));

    require(ecrecover(h, v, r, s) == admin);
    require(ecrecover(h, v2, r2, s2) == emergencyAdmin);

    admin = newAdmin;
    emergencyAdmin = newEmergencyAdmin;
}

function prefixedHash(bytes message) private pure returns (bytes32) {
    bytes32 h = keccak256(message);
    return keccak256(abi.encodePacked("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", h));
}
```

Comment: doesn't "abi.encodePacked" make the call more expensive than passing a parameter? or is more data in the parameters more expensive? in this case it would not matter anyways because i hopefully don't have to call this often. but im just asking because i use similar functions with signed messages that are called a lot more frequently and depending on the cost i would adapt them to your version.

Comment: Well, `keccak256` with multiple parameters is deprecated, and passing a single `bytes` parameter obtained via `abi.encodePacked` is the replacement. I _assume_ that `keccak256(a, b)` has the same gas cost as `keccak256(abi.encodePacked(a, b))`, but I honestly have not checked.